# libclang: парсинг .h файлов

Tags: c++, clang, libclang

libclang по-умолчанию обрабатывает .h файлы как файлы содержащие код на C.

Например, обход AST следующего класса:

```
class Session
{
protected:
    const std::string m_username;
    unsigned          m_id;
};
```

дает результат:

```
cursor: Session, kind: VarDecl
```

Если же изменить расширение файла, содержащего определение вышеупомянутого класса, на hpp, libclang начинает правильно парсить AST:

```
cursor: Session, of kind ClassDecl4
cursor: , of kind CXXAccessSpecifier39
cursor: m_username, of kind FieldDecl6
cursor: m_id, of kind FieldDecl6
```

Собственно, вопрос: так как путь к файлу передается именно в `clang_parseTranslationUnit` (см. код ниже), то можно ли последнюю "заставить" обрабатывать .h файл, как файл, содержащий C++ код?

Код для проверки:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <clang-c/Index.h>

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const CXString& str)
{
    os << clang_getCString(str);
    clang_disposeString(str);
    return os;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    auto idx = clang_createIndex(0, 0);
    auto unit = clang_parseTranslationUnit(idx, argv[1], nullptr, 0, nullptr, 0, CXTranslationUnit_None);

    if (!unit)
        return -1;

    auto cursor = clang_getTranslationUnitCursor(unit);

    clang_visitChildren(cursor, [](CXCursor c, CXCursor, CXClientData)
        {
            std::cout << "cursor: " << clang_getCursorSpelling(c) << ", "
                      << "kind: " << clang_getCursorKindSpelling(clang_getCursorKind(c)) << std::endl;
            return CXChildVisit_Recurse;
        },
        nullptr);

    clang_disposeTranslationUnit(unit);
    clang_disposeIndex(idx);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Добавить `-x c++` в `argv`?

Comment: @arrowd, да, это действительно исправило ситуацию. Спасибо за помощь! Может быть вынесете это в ответ, что бы я мог его принять?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Опции парсера задаются такими же флагами, которыми задается поведение самого `clang` при компиляции.

В частности, это означает что можно добавить `-x c++` в массив `argv` при вызове `clang_parseTranslationUnit`, для того чтобы указать в каком режиме парсить файл. Еще часто приходится указывать стандарт C++, например `-std=c++14`.